# HTML5 messes up gradient

Tags: css, html, gradient, radial

After i changed the doctype to html5 the background gradient messes up and looks like this:
[image: Messy]

if i remove it again it becomes a smooth gradient again.

My CSS code is the following:

```
body {
background: #3c99d4;
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #81e8f9 0%, #0358b5 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#81e8f9), color-stop(100%,#0358b5));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #81e8f9 0%,#0358b5 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #81e8f9 0%,#0358b5 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #81e8f9 0%,#0358b5 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #81e8f9 0%,#0358b5 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#81e8f9', endColorstr='#0358b5',GradientType=1 );}
```

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers or just a specific one?

Comment: Put what you have on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Seems to happen in all browsers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FWs5j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a height to both the `<html>` and `<body>` elements if you'd like the gradient to fill the viewport:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xZKPJ/3/

Comment: That worked. I'm a little embrassed that it was that easy. :I Thanks a lot!